# GPIO mode register

Tags: c++, embedded, gpio, stm32f4discovery

I've adjusted the example from [here](http://hertaville.com/2012/07/28/stm32f0-gpio-tutorial-part-1/) for the STM3240G-EVAL board in order to blink LEDs 3 and 4. I have it working, but am confused by the Mode register setting:

```
GPIOG->MODER |= (GPIO_MODER_MODER6_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODER8_0) ;
```

When I read the [reference manual](http://udel.edu/~furkan/cpeg423/13summer/stm32f4/DM00031020.pdf) (p186), it claims that the mode must be set to 01 for output, yet setting it to 0 in this way works just fine. Ideally I'd like to be able to change to the other modes, but I would have assumed that the above code would have changed pins 6 and 8 of port G to input pins. I must be missing something.

Here's my complete main document in case it's relevant:

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"

/* We will use PG6 and PG8 connected to LEDs 1 and 2 because they're the same port. */
/* Find base register value for Port G                                              */


void delay (int a);

int main(void)
{
  /*!< At this stage the microcontroller clock setting is already configured,
       this is done through SystemInit() function which is called from startup
       file (startup_stm32f0xx.s) before to branch to application main.
       To reconfigure the default setting of SystemInit() function, refer to
       system_stm32f0xx.c file
    */

    /* GPIOG Periph clock enable */
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOGEN;

GPIOG->MODER |= (GPIO_MODER_MODER6_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODER8_0) ;
    /* Configure PG6 and PG8 in output  mode  */

GPIOG->OTYPER &= ~(GPIO_OTYPER_OT_6 | GPIO_OTYPER_OT_8) ;
// Ensure push pull mode selected--default

GPIOG->OSPEEDR |= (GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR6|GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR8);
//Ensure maximum speed setting (even though it is unnecessary)

GPIOG->PUPDR &= ~(GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR6|GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR8);
//Ensure all pull up pull down resistors are disabled

while (1)
{
    /* Set PG6 and PG8 */
    /* the bit set/reset low register SETS the output data register     */
    /* the bit set/reset high register RESETS the output data register  */

    GPIOG -> BSRRL = (1 << 6);
    GPIOG -> BSRRL = (1 << 8);
    delay(500000);
    /* Reset PC8 and PC9 */
    GPIOG -> BSRRH = (1 << 6);
    GPIOG -> BSRRH = (1 << 8);
    delay(500000);
    }

return 0;
} 

void delay (int a)
{
volatile int i,j;

for (i=0 ; i < a ; i++)
{
    j++;
}

return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting it to zero, you're setting it to one.

The definition of the `GPIO_MODER_MODER6_0` constant is `0x00001000`. The mask for the `GPIO_MODER_MODER6` bits is `0x00003000`, so you're putting bits `01` into the right place.

If the constant `GPIO_MODER_MODER6_0` were defined as zero, then or'ing it into the configuration register would have no effect in any case. To set both bits to zero you'd need to do something like:

```
GPIOG->MODER &= ~(GPIO_MODER_MODER6_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODER6_1);
```

The `_0` and `_1` suffixes refer to the bit numbers for masking, not the values being written.